# Which is the best format to save a slideshow in OpenShot?

Tags: mac, format, slideshow, openshot

My school laptop was recently taken up, which is a Macbook Air.  And I didn't have the chance to create my slideshow before it was taken up, so, I did some research and found that OpenShot was most similar to iMovie on Mac.

My question is, what is the best format to save it in, in order to burn it on a disc so that it's good quality and takes up the screen, as in full screen.  When I try saving it, it shows me all of these different formats and I'm just not sure which is best.

When I used iMovie, which was only a couple of times, I believe I saved it in mpeg-4.  And that seemed to work fine to play on the computer and to upload online, but I just want to be sure I'm using the best one. If anyone can help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `avi` and `mpeg4` format. Those are more popular and compatible with almost every platform. You can also use the `mov` format, which is default on Mac.

You can also use `wmv` format as [this answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080712102052AAzpeim) suggests.

If you want higher quality, Try using HD format.

---

**Codecs/formats** missing error:

These errors are showing because, Openshot requires some enhanced codecs to performs video conversions which are not available from multiverse repository due to licensing issue in some country. So, **Be sure to check the local law about using proprietary codecs before doing the following procedure**.

To be able to use those enhanced codecs, you need to add "medibuntu" repository and install the enhanced ones.

1. Go to [this Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu/#Adding_the_Repository) and follow the procedure to add medibuntu repository.
2. Do `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal
3. Install the codecs with this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53 libavdevice-extra-53 libavfilter-extra-53 libavformat-extra-53 libavutil-extra-53 libswscale-extra-2 libpostproc-extra-52
   ```

   This command is for Ubuntu 12.04. In earlier versions, the package name may contain `52` or `51` in their name.

   Additionally, You can install `libdvdcss2` and `not-free-codecs` too. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu/#Playing_Encrypted_DVDs) for more help.

Comment: I used the "AVI(mpeg-4)" format for the target, "HDV 1080 25i 1920*1080" for the video profile and "High" for the quality.  It then came up and said:  "The following formats/codecs are missing from your system:

libmp3lame

You will not be able to use the selected export profile.  You will need to install the missing formats/codecs or choose a different export profile."

I installed the missing format and retried it.  It came up with the same message despite already installing it and restarting the program.

Comment: @Aubrey Sorry, for late reply. You need to install some codecs from medibuntu repository. I have edited my answer.